# How to make a existing column "unique" in PowerBI, so I can form a "one-to-many" relationsship?

Tags: powerbi

I have 40 tables. One table has 20 rows, and one of the columns have 1385 distinct values.
I would like to use this in a relationship with another table.

> TableName(1385 rows) Column:Name:(1385 distinct values)

But when I try to do this in Powerbi/Manage-Relations, it will only accept the option "Many-to-Many" relationship. It reports that none of the column are "Unique".

Well, the data in the column is unique. So how can I configure this column to be unique so I can use it in a "One-to-Many" relationship"?

Do I have to edit the DAX expression and put the "DISTINCT" keyword in the expression for that column? And How?

Now I have:

```
    }, {"Columnname", Int64.Type}, {
```

Comment: well this usually works directly i.e powerbi would automatically see if the values are unique....just to confirm if the values in the column are unique: just do count of  each value of that column, maybe through the table visual.

Comment: I have already done that. And all values have a count of '1'

Comment: One of the Tables are defined as DIrectQuery Storage Mode, and the other table is IMPORT mode and from a csv file. Could there be some limitations related to Direct Query that inhibits this?

Comment: i don't think so.. what you can try is to perform remove duplicates in that table(i know its already contains distinct values but you can give it a try)... and/or just load the data again.

Comment: @sanjeev_gautam yes, excellent. This solved it. I did a "Remove Duplicates" on both tables. And now a One-to-Many is accepted. (Both tables still contains the same number of rows though, so data has not changed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can try is to perform remove duplicates in that table(i know its already contains distinct values but you can give it a try)... and/or just load the data again.

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be when you group your data in the query editor. This way your table has only distinct values and you can create your relationship.

In the query designer under `Home > Group By` you can group after your column.

**Example**

Table:

[image]

Table (2):

[image]

Relationship (One to Many):

[image]

Result:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: 1. I tried this, however i dont see how this can solve it, the problem remains. 2. As stated in the Original Post, the values are unique. PowerBI just dont understand it...

Comment: You can test it. Group just this one column and count the values. Now do the same with your unique table. If the count matches you have unique values if not you dont. Is the type of your relationship columns the same? Because ´Integer` to `string` doesnt work. Normally Power BI detects exactly what realtionship you have and tells you what is wrong or not.

Comment: Good suggestions, but it seems to be of equal type: {"id", Int64.Type}, so matches type I specified in OP

Comment: Ok, i did some more researh. In Table X i have the 1385 unique rows. In table B i have 200 unique values but 8000 rows. (of the same values as A). So does that mean I cant releate them? And with this structure, will i have to use queries to present the data instead? IF EXISTS.... and so on?

Comment: Nah a one to many should work. I posted an example in the answer above.